# Spring Security and Sharepoint 2010 SSO

Tags: sharepoint, spring-security

What is the easiest and most standard way to authenticate from Sharepoint 2010 to a Spring Security Application?

An authenticated user in Sharepoint follows a link, and it is automatically logged into the Spring application.

What are the options?

Thanks and regards!

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK there is no out of the box Spring Security/Sharepoint integration. We're in the process of writing our own integration framework for this. In simple terms it goes something like this:

1. User tries to access a resource which is protected by Spring
2. User is redirected to Sharepoint/IIS
3. Sharepoint/IIS authenticates user if not already authenticated
4. Sharepoint/IIS redirects/posts a securityassertion back to Spring
   which is digitally signed
5. Spring verifies assertion is authentic and creates a local security
   context

The protocol is based on SAML2

Drop me a message if you want to know more about this or follow our [blog](http://www.cloudseal.com/category/general/) for updates